# pandas equivalent to numpy.roll

Tags: python, numpy, pandas

I have a pandas dataframe and I'd like to add a new column that has the contents of an existing column, but shifted relative to the rest of the data frame. I'd also like the value that drops off the bottom to get rolled around to the top.

For example if this is my dataframe:

```
>>> myDF
   coord  coverage
0      1         1
1      2        10
2      3        50
```

I want to get this:

```
>>> myDF_shifted
   coord  coverage  coverage_shifted
0      1         1                50
1      2        10                 1
2      3        50                10
```

(This is just a simplified example - in real life, my dataframes are larger and I will need to shift by more than one unit)

This is what I've tried and what I get back:

```
>>> myDF['coverage_shifted'] = myDF.coverage.shift(1)
>>> myDF
   coord  coverage  coverage_shifted
0      1         1               NaN
1      2        10                 1
2      3        50                10
```

So I can create the shifted column, but I don't know how to roll the bottom value around to the top. From internet searches I think that numpy lets you do this with "numpy.roll". Is there a pandas equivalent?

Comment: You can do, i.e. `myDF['coverage_shifted'] = np.roll(df.coverage, 2)`, for shifting 2 positions.

Comment: That works great! Thanks, @CTZhu!

Comment: For what you want to achieve using `np.roll` is better as the np array returned will not force any alignment on index values which is what you want in this case

Answer (score 9):

Pandas probably doesn't provide an off-the-shelf method to do the exactly what you described, however if you can move a little but out of the box, `numpy` has [exactly that](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.roll.html)

In your case it is:

```
import numpy as np
myDF['coverage_shifted'] = np.roll(df.coverage, 2)
```

Answer (score 1):

You can pass in an additional argument to the `shift()` to achieve what you want. The previous answer is much more helpful in most cases

```py
last_value = myDF.iloc[-1]['coverage']
myDF['coverage_shifted'] = myDF.coverage.shift(1, fill_value=last_value)
```

You have to manually supply the value to `fill_value`

same can be applied for reverse rolling

```py
first_value = myDF.iloc[0]['coverage']
myDF['coverage_back_shifted'] = myDF.coverage.shift(-1, fill_value=first_value)
```