# Changing the order of a DataFrame by 1 in paython

Tags: pandas, dataframe

I have the following data frame:
`df = [NaT, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5]`
and I am trying to get the following data frame of the previous one but with changing the order, something like this:
`df = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, NaT]`

Any help would be very appreciated. Thank you in advance

Comment: Perhaps [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32257276/pandas-equivalent-to-numpy-roll) is more closer to what you need?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `.sort_values` to sort the dataframe:

```
df = pd.DataFrame([pd.NaT, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5])
df = df.sort_values(by=[0]) # replace 0 with your column name
```

Which results in:

```
    0
1   1
2   2
3   3
4   4
5   5
0   NaT
```

Comment: well, I just have done it on my machine, the order changed in a random way.

Comment: @DaveWill Perhaps if you could post your code and the output, then it will be easier to see what is happening for you.

Answer (score 0):

Use python numpy

```
import numpy as np
array = np.array([1,2,3,4,5])
array_new = np.roll(array, 1)
print(array_new)
```